# Is working on the same set of muscles in a day a sound advice for muscle building, what is the scientific reasoning behind it?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle

My gymmates told me that if I want to build my muscles, I should concentrate on one part of muscles ( eg: biceps) in one day, then move on to the next part of the muscles the other day. Never ever workout on two or more different parts of muscles on the same day because the muscles won't be built up that way.

I don't find this a compelling argument because if you keep on working out on a part of the muscles, it will experience fatigue and hence the benefit will be diminishing. Won't it be better to train on different part of muscles so that resting time is properly given to the tired muscles?

Who's right on this? What is the proper workout routines as far as muscle building is concerned?

Comment: @JohnP, no, it's not a duplicate. I've edited to explain why

Comment: @EricKaufman, it's not a dupe. I've edited to explain why

Comment: It's just not a good question, and if you re-wrote it into other better questions *those* would be duplicates. Seriously, your friends have no idea what they're talking about and you should go with stronglifts 5x5 or starting strength. Or you'll just waste a bunch of time, get injured, get frustrated, and then switch to them later.

Comment: @Graviton - Your basic question is "What is the proper workout routines for building muscle", which is covered quite nicely by the two linked duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general question but you could try 'starting strength' or '5x5 stronglifts' for overall training plans.

What you're describing sounds like bodybuilding split training, which does involve training different groups of muscles on different days.

When you are working out you're breaking down the muscle through micro tears and only through rest will it 'build'.

Only training biceps on a day sounds like broscience.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends upon your frequency and intensity if workout, it depends on your goals too, a muscle takes 48 hours to recover after workout, so you should just see to it that there is a window of 48hours between your workout for same muscle 
You can follow 1 day 1 muscle or
A n B on first day 
C n D on second day 
E on third day or rest if you need, 
Again A n B on fourth day and so on.

Comment: Rate of recovery is not necessarily 48 hours. There are lots of factors that go into how long recovery can take. Sleep, caloric intake, type of training, training history, etc.